# Angular2 HTTP GET parameter inside URL

Tags: angular

I would like to call REST service GET method with with Angular2 HTTP and parameter "searchId" inside the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/name/:searchId/documents/
```

In AngularJS it was quite easy:

```
       getDataResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEntityResource> {
        console.log("REST CALL");
        return this.$resource("http://localhost:8080/services/name/:searchId/documents/", {searchId: "12345678"}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }
```

Can you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it is unfortunately simple concatenation:

```
getData(searchId:number):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(http://localhost:8080/services/name/"+searchId.toString()+"/documents/";
}
```

More informations on [Http Client documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can you template string interpolation to achieve this:
use back tick to achieve it. so instead of `""` use `` and instead of  `:searchId` use `$searchId`

```
return this.$resource(

`http://localhost:8080/services/name/${searchId} /documents/`

)
.someMethod();
```

for more info look [here](http://learnangular2.com/es6/template-strings/)

Comment: That's not valid syntax. It should be `${ searchId }` inside of the string.